# How to autozoom to width in Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I really like how Chrome PDF viewer provides a zoom to document width button.  Is there such a thing in Microsoft Word 2010?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under View you have different options to see your page, including **Page Width**.